# I18n and Interpolation?

Tags: ruby, regex, middleman, string-interpolation

I want to be able interpolate variables inside of strings stored in a yml locales file. The only way I have figured out how to do this is with regex.

For example in en.yml I have

```
---
en:
  byline: "By <strong>{{author}}</strong>"`
```

And then in my erb file I have:

`<%= t(:byline).gsub!(/{{author}}/, current_page.data.author) %>`

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

See [Passing Variables to Translations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations) in the Rails Internationalization API RailsGuide:

> You can use variables in the translation messages and pass their values from the view.

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%=t 'greet_username', user: "Bill", message: "Goodbye" %>

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
```